# script only executed once

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have created a web component and used in two different places as follows.

```
    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Users in Debt</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by user name" class="input_style">

        <my-component filter="userdebt"></my-component>


    </div>

    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Debts</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by debt description" class="input_style">

        <my-component filter="debt"></my-component>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see i have used `<my-component filter="userdebt"></my-component>` in 2 places.

Here i'll show my web component

```
        connectedCallback() {
            console.log("ABC");
            window.globalVar = this.getAttribute("filter");


            this.innerHTML = `
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="templates">
    <template id="book-template">
        <li><span class="title"></span> &mdash; <span class="author"></span></li>
    </template>


    <ul id="books"></ul>

    </div>
    <script type="module" src="./js/testingjs.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

    `;

            var yourElement = document.getElementById('templates');
            yourElement.id = globalVar;
            console.log("MyComp ", yourElement.id);


        }

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

But even though i have used `my-component` twice in the html i can see the console.log only once meaning it's executing only once. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Your component code does not look complete in your example.

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript ES6 module is only loaded the first time it's needed.

Therefore its content is only executed once (when it is loaded).

You should call explicitly a function defined in the Javascript module in `connectedCallback()` method if you want it to be exectuted for each custom element created.